# Google Primary Calendar for user contains no ConferenceProperties or no AllowedConferenceSolutionTypes

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Google Calendar API for export events to user's primary calendar.

I get the following error during creation for hangoutsMeet type for only one of 3K+ users and user's primary calendar either contains no ConferenceProperties or no ConferenceProperties.AllowedConferenceSolutionTypes.

> "Code: 400, Message: Invalid conference type value."

```
CalendarService service;
var primaryCalendar = service.Calendars.Get("primary").Execute();

var allowedTypes = (primaryCalendar.ConferenceProperties != null && 
primaryCalendar.ConferenceProperties.AllowedConferenceSolutionTypes  != null)  ? primaryCalendar.ConferenceProperties.AllowedConferenceSolutionTypes.JoinAsString(",") : "N/A";
```

I get "N/A" for only one of them.

Thus I suppose that this is user's calendar settings. Could anybody advise what exactly should be corrected?

Thank you

Comment: Can you check that the user who you are having an issue with is a service account and not an actual user.

Comment: Good question. Thank you. I've never thought about this. At the moment all I know it that this user authorized in Google via Oath2 and I have their refresh token.

Comment: Service accounts also have refresh tokens, [source](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#expiration), can you confirm that its not a service account? I think we would at least need more information on the user and if they have any specific calendar settings. Or any more debugging info / test results that you may have.